# No sales on date show zero in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server. Please tell me how to solve this issue in SQL Server

I have a table with two columns `sale_date` and `amount`:

```
sale_date     amount
-------------------
05/01/2014    400
05/02/2014    350
05/04/2014    430
.
.
```

but I want the output to include a value of zero for `amount` if there are no sales for a particular month.

Like this:

```
sale_date    amount
-------------------
05/01/2014    400
05/02/2014    350
05/03/2014      0
05/04/2014    430
.
.
```

Please tell me how to solve this in SQL Server

Comment: One way to do it is to use a table of numbers or calendar table: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html suggested solution by Sarath Avanavu generates such table on the fly using recursive CTE. There are many ways to generate a table of numbers: http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(sale_date DATE, AMOUNT NUMERIC(18,2))

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
SELECT '05/01/2014',   400
UNION ALL
SELECT '05/02/2014',    350
UNION ALL
SELECT '05/04/2014',    430
```

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @MAXDATE DATE
SELECT @MAXDATE = MAX(sale_date) FROM #TEMP

; WITH  CTE as
 (
     -- Select minimum date
     SELECT MIN(sale_date) as DATES
     FROM #TEMP    
     UNION ALL
     -- Increments month recursively till maximum date
     SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,DATES)
     FROM    CTE C1     
     WHERE   DATES < @MAXDATE
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT DATES,ISNULL(T1.AMOUNT ,0)AMOUNT
 FROM    CTE C1
 LEFT JOIN #TEMP T1 ON C1.DATES=T1.sale_date
```

Comment: I have updated. Feel free to ask for any change. @user1623352

Comment: Thank you. Please mark this as answer. by clicking the **TICK** button on the left side of answer. @user1623352